# SQL SERVER insert / update record of table by table valued parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Stored Procedure that takes Table valued Parameter as input . It has around 15-20 columns.
          I want to perform insert / update without MERGE  since, by MERGE there is lock on table . Also by doing research i came to know , cursors can also be used. But CURSORs degrades performance .
          I found this article( https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/sql-server-cursor-alternatives  ) , in that inside while loop we get each column variable , it would be tedious with tables having columns greater than 10.  So, is there any other option for me?

Comment: What's your exact problem? You cannot perform inserts or updates without taking row locks, nor is that *normally* a problem. This is true whether you use `MERGE` or `INSERT`/`UPDATE`. If it is a problem, you can look into things like snapshot isolation, which use optimistic concurrency to avoid locking but abort an update if modifications are detected. In no case does involving cursors improve anything. Nor is it clear why the number of columns is relevant -- rows are always locked as a whole, not on a per-column basis.

Comment: Besides the excellent points raised by Jeroen, cursors are bad for performance because they work row-by-row. Replacing them with a while loop to iterate row-by-row will solve nothing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert in that link that i have posted, it shows how to use cursors in while loop to retrieve data , further inside WHILE LOOP, they created seperate variable to capture data from particular column of row. 
       And assume if we use this in table where there are more than 15-25 columns , it would be not good coding practise. That is what i was asking for; something better than this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a **stored procedure** and pass your parameter like below code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
    @TableValue [dbo].[TABLETYPE] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
    SET Name = T.Name
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
        INNER JOIN @TableValue AS T ON T.Id = [dbo].[MyTable].Id
    WHERE T.Name <> [dbo].[MyTable].Name

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable](Id,Name)
    SELECT Id , Name
    FROM @TableValue AS T
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                     FROM [dbo].[MyTable] 
                     WHERE Id = T.Id)
END
GO
```

First update existing records,Then insert new rows.

Comment: THIS WAS WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR

Comment: we can avoid join by following code

 UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
    SET Name = T.Name
    FROM @TableValue T
     WHERE (t.Name <> [dbo].[MyTable].Name AND  T.Id =[dbo].[MyTable].Id)

Answer (score -2):

I create a sample for you. It is easy.
You can put it in your stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME_DEST VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(4000)

SET @TABLE_NAME = 'Employee'
SET @TABLE_NAME_DEST = 'Employee_DEST'

SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ', ', '') + Column_Name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME
-- Prevent Injection
IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME )) 
BEGIN
SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO [' + @TABLE_NAME_DEST +'] (' + @List +')' +char(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT ' + @List + char(10) + 'FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME

print @SQL
END
```

Similar for SQL Update.

Comment: This is just horrible. It is wide open to sql injection. Please do not use any code like this.

Comment: He may like a dymanic SQL? Please see "Table valued Parameter as input"

Comment: They are trying to solve a performance problem. Just throwing out a dynamic sql solution is not a good approach. And if you want to suggest a table valued parameter, by all means, update your answer. That would definitely improve it.

Comment: The cursor is slow, I provide SQL Insert/Update which may be better. Add some more code to prevent Injection!

Comment: I update the answer, I don't think that someone creates a table name 'DELETE FROM XX'

Comment: But if you put this as a stored procedure those would be inbound parameters and your code is wide open to sql injection. I am afraid that your solution is just not a viable answer to the issue at hand.

Comment: He (Dashang TravelCue) can get the print out of @SQL and put the string some where in his stored procedure, he tired of edit 20 fields.

Comment: I give up....you need to read about and understand sql injection because your solution is highly vulnerable to that.

Comment: I added code to prevent Injection, it is OK? Can you remove down vote and waiting for Dashang TravelCue?

Comment: The OP says they already have a solution with a table valued parameter. I can't see how this would improve what they have. And this doesn't protect anything from an injection attack. I'm not sure what it has to do with the question, which is asking about insert/update a given set of values: This just copies from one table to another.

Comment: *"He can get the print out of @SQL and put the string some where in his stored procedure, he tired of edit 20 fields."* That isn't what the OPs problem is. You have definitely misunderstood.

Comment: VinhCC  , Richardissimo and @SeanLange Thanks for comments and sample code, but i dont think dynamic sql is good idea. I have stored procedure which takes  table valued parameter as input and the table valued parameter and corresponding table has 20 columns . if i refer that article mentioned in question, it doesnt look good taking each column in seperate variable . i was looking for code optimization or alternative and possible if we can eleminate 
 use of cursors  ..it would be more better

Comment: @DashangTravelCue I don't think there was any doubt from Sean or myself that this was not what you were looking for.